# Copying variable into dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier variable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Say I initialize a variable `cell` for use in a `UICollectionView`

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell;
```

Now if I set `cell` to another variable with base-class `MyCustomCell` I lose the reuse identifier and end up getting a crash later on in the program:

```
cell = myCustomCellInstance;
```

Is there any way to avoid having to perform a copy by hand? I.e. going through every property and performing a copy:

```
cell.property1 = myCustomCellInstance.property1
cell.property2 = myCustomCellInstance.property2
```

etc.

Comment: What do you mean you "lose the reuse identifier"?  When you say `cell = myCustomCellInstance` you are changing the cell instance that `cell` *refers to*, you are not assigning the property values from `myCustomCellInstance` to `cell`. If that is what you want to do, then that is what you must do (using the code you have shown).  But perhaps you could explain what you are actually trying to achieve and we can give an answer

Comment: Yes thats exactly the problem. By lose the "reuse identifier" I mean that I lose the purpose of initializing the with the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` function. The UICollectionView class requires that custom cells be initialized with this function and changing what cell refers to breaks this. I want to achieve something similar to what C++ achieves with a copy constructor, except I don't see a clear way of doing that in the context of the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

Comment: Right, so why are you trying to copy the properties from some other cell object.  Why aren't you assigning them from your data model object?

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning from your data model object"?

Comment: Well, normally you would have an array that contained the information that you want to display in your cells. This is the "model" in the "Model-view-controller" MVC pattern.  In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you dequeue a cell and then assign the values from the array into the cell's views

Comment: In relation to your earlier comment, you can use the `copy` function on an object that conforms to the `Copyable` protocol; this is the equivalent of C++'s copy constructor, but as in C++ this will return a new instance of the object class, it won't simply assign properties to an existing instance.

Comment: Also, you can return instances of cells that don't come from`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, you just won't get the benefit of cell reuse, so your memory footprint will likely be higher.  Any crash you are seeing isn't directly related to that

Comment: Thats exactly the design pattern of my program. My question then is how do I assign the values from my data model object? Clearly I cannot just change the reference of the original dequeued object to the object from the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129713/discussion-between-paulw11-and-orange-juice).